# Remove invalid "moving" entry from Google Maps' Timeline?

Tags: google-maps

Is there some hidden way to remove an invalid "moving" (driving/flying/...) entry from the Google Maps timeline without deleting the whole day?
For "stops" there's a menu next to it where I can remove it, but there is no such menu for the entry that's actually incorrect...

[image]

Unfortunately pretty much everything found on Google about this is just about disabling the whole feature (which I don't want, because I consider it useful - when it works correctly!)

In case anyone wonders how this happened in the first place: I'm currently on a ship and I forgot to disable location services on my phone. Usually I turn them on only when on deck / going to shore, but since I left them enabled, they ended up using the Wifi networks to determine the location as there's no GPS reception inside the ship. But since the ship's network is found all over the world (wherever the ship is), it gives me completely wrong locations (sometimes just the wrong country, sometimes it even puts me in the US even though I'm in europe).

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old question but have been 8 months now since it was posted and there is no answer yet, so, as I just figure it out how to do it, I want to share the solution.

You just need to set the time from one of the stops (locations) to cover the time of the wrong moving entry that you want to delete, at that moment you will see a message that says, “This change will affect your visit to *****”, just click on SAVE and it’s done.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this only hides the wrong movement, at least for me. After I do this, and everything looks ok on the map (there's no travel between locations, teleportation ftw!, but all the places are good) I then fix the times, or remove a fake location. And all the wrong movement reappears! My wrong movement is caused by Maps thinking my router is in my old house, 100's of kilometers from my new house.. every day it thinks I'm making 5 minute 800km trips to the shops... :(